# Why is Boolean values in request.POST is Unicode format?

Tags: python, django

(1)I designed a API application. Some arguments in API expected it will receive Boolean datas.

Example:

```
def hello(request):
    # request.POST.viewitems()
    # {u'is_logined': u'False', u'user': u'hello'}
    user_name = request.POST.get("user", "") # "hello"
    is_logined = request.POST.get("is_logined", "") # "False"
```

This is my sending:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test"
aaa= {"user": "hello",
          "is_logined": False}
res = requests.post(url, data=aaa)
```

I suppose I get the argument is a boolean data but it's Unicode format.
Anyone know why it is Unicode format.

(2)I have another question. If java program will access my API, I know boolean in java is `false` and `true`.

When my API receive the boolean data, is it still `false` and `true` of Unicode string?

Comment: No-one can tell why you're getting that data, since you didn't provide any code that shows how you're posting it.

Comment: Please provide the code for more help. But this boils down to your "data interchange format" that you choose. Usually this is JSON. So you need to serialize your data to json string and post that json string as a payload. In your code your deserialize your POST payload form json into a dict and your booleans wont be strings. This works on many major languages even in Java. You just need JSON libraries which is standard in python.

Comment: You do realise within request there is a user object which holds the authentication details of the current user. `request.user.is_authenticated()` and `request.user.username`

Comment: I have provided my code.

Comment: No you haven't, you've provided the code that processes the post. What is sending it in the first place?

Comment: Do you mean my accessing method? I have provided my code.

Comment: you have params =, then have param.  Not sure if that is a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the POST method, in which the browser bundles up the form data, encodes it for transmission, sends it back to the server, and then receives its response.

I guess you use form to send data. The data type of sending provides Text and File formats. So, this is why you receive is Text. If you know a app it's name postman, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an straightforward answer to you question, but this is one of the reasons why you should use forms to process posted data. Through forms api you will have the "right" python object type.

Other reasons are mainly security.